# How to process a large text file to get part of this file more efficiently?

Tags: python, dataset

I have a text file like this:

```
  A B C D E F ... X Y Z
a 1 0 1 2 1 0 ... 1 0 2
b 1 2 0 1 1 2 ... 1 0 0
c . . . . . . ..... . .
d . . . . . . ..... . .
e . . . . . . ..... . .
f . . . . . . ..... . .
. . . . . . . ..... . .
. . . . . . . ..... . .
. . . . . . . ..... . .
x 1 0 1 2 1 0 ... 1 0 2
y 0 0 1 0 1 1 ... 1 0 2
z 1 2 0 1 1 2 ... 1 0 0
```

what i need to do is that :load this file and get 1000 lines of E&F rows to a new text file
I had used itertools to load this large file but can't to get E&F rows efficient

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
from itertools import islice
fout = open('a.txt','w')
with open('b.txt','r') as fin:
    n = 50
    while n > 0:
    next_n_lines = list(islice(fin,0,20))
    if not next_n_lines:
        break
    fout.write(''.join(next_n_lines))
    n = n - 1
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```
with open('a.txt','w') as fout:
    with open('b.txt','r') as fin:
        lines_done=0
        fin.readline() # skip the first line ("  A B C D E F ... X Y Z" in your example)
        # fout.write("E F\n") # uncomment this line if you want the column headings in fout
        for line in fin:  
            if lines_done>=1000: # you said 100 lines only
                break     
            ef=line[10:13] # solution A
            # ef=" ".join(line.split()[5:7]) # solution B
            fout.write(ef+"\n")
            lines_done+=1
```

please make sure if  which solution you need

- **A** works on your example data (E at 10, F at 12) and is faster
- **B** works on more general whitespace-seperated lines (E 5th entriy in row, F
  6th entry in row) and is a bit slower

Answer (score 0):

Since columns are separated by ' ' You can use [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split).

```
def extract(nin,nout,cidx,rows):
    with open(nout,'w') as fout:        
        with open(nin,'r') as fin:
            offest = 0
            for line in fin:
                 cols = line.strip().split(' ')
                 for cc in cidx:
                     fout.write(cols[cc+offest] )
                     fout.write(' ')
                 fout.write('\n')
                 offest = 1
                 rows -= 1
                 if rows == 0:
                     break                     
extract('b.txt','a.txt',[4,5],1000)
```

Comment: it works well!!U save me a lot of time!!One more question is that can this code work quicker?

Comment: I do not think you can make it quicker since it already process the file line by line

Comment: yeah,I think it is much better than mine:)